# Why is my mic so quiet in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I have a Dell Inspiron 1520. Under Ubuntu 9.04, my mic is extremely quiet. Under Windows the mic is a good volume. I have crawled through alsa-mixer and all the sound options I can find in Ubuntu, but I can't get the volume above a whisper level.

Any ideas?

Update:

If I right click on a Volume Control icon and choose Volume Control I get This

Here is what is in this window. This is 2 levels, the first is the tabs, and the second is the things in the tabs

- Playback  *(All three of these control my system volume)*

  - Master
  - PCM
  - Front
- Recording *(All of these options are turned up to 100% and not muted)*

  - Capture
  - Capture 1
  - Digital
  - Mux
  - Mux 1
- Switches

  - IEC958 [Checked]
  - IEC958 Default PCM [Checked]
  - Analog Loopback [Not Checked]
- Options

  - IEC958 Playback Source (Digital Playback, other choices are Mux and Mux 1)
  - Digital Input Source (Digial Mic 1, other choice is Analog Inputs)
  - Input Source (Mic, no other options)
  - Input Source (Mic, no other options)
- Sound Theme (excluded)

I have checked everything in the preferences window that comes up from the button below.

Answer (score 16):

I had this issue with Ubuntu 18.04. On Windows 10 (dual boot), microphone works as expected. On Ubuntu, I could yell into the microphone and you could barely hear anything on the other end. None of the built-in settings were working including boosting the microphone. I finally found [this](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/507291-Microphone-volume-very-low-when-routed-through-Pulseaudio?s=3e928b7008b05a03e7bc021355371827&p=2709188#post2709188) suggestion which originates from [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=183740#p952175).

1. Install `pavucontrol`
2. Run `pavucontrol` and go to the `Input Devices` tab
3. Click the unlock button to unlock the channels
4. Set the `Right` channel to 0 (left should be above 0, possibly 100%)

I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Struggled hopelessly until we installed `pavucontrol`, and now it's fine. Thanks!

Comment: It didn't work for me, still very quiet, in regular video calls. Is there a way to amplify the mic from the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Is 'Mic Boost' a valid option for you?

Click on the volume controller on the top right, choose 'Volume Control'. From the dialog, select 'Preferences' button, and fine '[ ] Mic Boost'. For some reason, it's under Playback (should be under recording), make sure it's not muted and raise it up.

Comment: There is no Mic Boost anywhere that I can find on my system. This is what I do in Windows to get it to be audible, but I can't find it in Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you update your question to list what is there?

Comment: This sounds like a driver 'issue' (unimplemented feature). Would you mind trying to pop a LiveCD of the latest alpha to check if any new drivers are available?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is over eleven years too late (and I'm sorry) but i fixed it by selecting the option that said multichannel instead of the one above it.[this is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDYRp.png)